# mootools recursive remove class

Tags: mootools

I want to remove classes in the particular div. I mean i have to remove the classname called "highlight" in the div id called "result". In the onclick event i want to remove all the "highlight" classes. How can i do it? Please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

easy.

```
document.id("result").getElements(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
```

Comment: Damn Dimitar, You're on-top of all the Mootools Questions.